# git pull --rebase --preserve-merges rewrites merge commit with unmodified parents

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-pull

consider the history

```
   D  origin/master
  /
 | C  master
 | |\
 | | B
  \|/|
   A :
   |
   :
```

After a `git pull --rebase --preserve-merges` I would expect the history to be

```
   C'  master
   |\
   D |
   | B
   |/|
   A :
   |
   :
```

But it turns out to be

```
   C'  master
   |\
   | B'
   |/|
   D :
   |
   A
   |
   :
```

In other words, the B commit is rewritten to B', even though there is no need for it, because both parents are unmodified. I get that I'm rebasing onto D, but it is problematic because all conflicts in the B merge have to be resolved again.

Is there a benefit to the current functionality?

Is there a way to get the functionality I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really answer the "benefit" question, but I can describe why rebase is acting as it is and how you can get the result you want.

Rebase, whether interactive or not, takes "three branch-or-commit-like" arguments, which it calls *`newbase`*, *`upstream`*, and *`branch`*:

> `git rebase` [`-i` | `--interactive`] [*`options`*] [`--exec cmd`] [`--onto newbase`]
>                       [*`upstream`* [*`branch`*]]

If you leave some or all of these out, rebase still uses them, it just finds them on their own:

- *`branch`* defaults to the current branch, or `HEAD` (including a detached head).
- *`upstream`* defaults to the current branch's upstream, as set by `git branch --set-upstream-to` or similar.  Whatever you specify here, or the default, is given to `git rev-list` to make it *stop* taking commits, i.e., the commits that will be rebased are those printed by `git rev-list upstream..HEAD`.
- `newbase` defaults to the same commit ID as *`upstream`*.

(These all get somewhat modified if you supply `--fork-point` in a git new enough to have `--fork-point`, but the general idea here still applies: the commits to be rebased are chosen based on those "after" upstream, up to and including HEAD, by default.)

When you let `git pull` run `git rebase` for you, it supplies, as the `upstream`, the actual upstream of the current branch (again, modified by fork-point computation in newer gits, but this should have no effect if your actual upstream from which you're fetching has not done its own rebasing).  (The `--onto` normally winds up being the same upstream as well.  In this case, it amounts to `git rebase [options] --onto origin/master origin/master master`.)

As you can see (by running `git rev-list origin/master..master`), this means "please rebase commits `B` and `C` onto `D`".  Adding `--preserve-merges` simply uses the interactive machinery and preserves the merge as requested, after rebasing both commits as requested.

If you simply run `git fetch`, you will obtain commit `D` as usual and have the graph you drew as the first one:

```
   D  origin/master
  /
 | C  master
 | |\
 | | B
  \|/|
   A :
   |
   :
```

You can now *try* to run `git rebase -p` manually to rebase commit `C`, specifying `B` as its "upstream" so that the rebase does not copy commit `B`, and specifying `D` as the `--onto` commit so that `C` is rebased onto `D`:

```
$ git rebase -p --onto origin/master master^2 master
```

Unfortunately, this makes a new merge commit whose two parents are `origin/master` (commit `D`) and the original `master^` (commit `A`).  (It's not immediately obvious why, although it clearly has to do with the way interactive-preserve-mode works internally.)

So, the trick in this case is to do your own merge:

```
$ git branch -m master old-master
$ git checkout master
```

(this makes a new `master` pointing to commit `D`), then:

```
$ git merge old-master^2
```

(this does a new merge of the unmodified `B`).

You also mention, though, that:

> ...  it is problematic because all conflicts in the B merge have to be resolved again.

Unfortunately, you can't truly avoid this, because it's possible that `D` is sufficiently different from `A` that the actual merge conflict resolutions should *also* differ.

If you're sure that they (the resolutions) should not (differ), you can side-step this issue as well, by obtaining the merge results from your old commit `C`.  Let's say, for instance, that the conflicts occur in `dir1/file1` and `dir2/file2`, while the difference between `A` and `D` is all in `README.txt` or some such.  Then, when you do the above merge, you can "resolve" the conflicts quite simply with:

```
$ git checkout old-master -- dir1/file1 dir2/file2
```

which extracts commit `C`'s versions of those files, updating your index and work-tree to recover your previous merge resolution.  Your conflicts are now resolved (exactly as before) and you can `git commit` the resulting merge.